# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '"...."' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    tMI.MI
FROM
    tMI
LEFT JOIN 
    tCard ON tCard.CardNumber = tMI.MI
INNER JOIN
    TMIN on TMIN.T_ID = tMI.MI
WHERE
    tCard.CardNumber IS NULL
    AND tMI.MI IS NOT NULL
```

I am running the above code and without the inner join it runs fine. But once I add the inner join, it falls saying it cannot convert.

The data is the same minus maybe a few extras here and there in the table.

Any ideas how I can get around this error?

Comment: You should post your table structure, sample data and expected results.  As is, your error suggests `t_id` and `mi` are different data types (you cannot simply join on `int` and `varchar`)...

Comment: check the datatypes of the columns TMIN.T_ID and tMI.MI. Most probably one of them is varchar (tMI.MI) and other is int (TMIN.T_ID). I suggest, Cast or Convert one of them for comparision.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, except I KNOW that both table columns are an int

Answer (score 1):

Check all the columns mentioned in your **ON** condition are of same data type.

If you are storing the CardNumber as `varchar` (which is actually an `integer` value) and Mi as Integer, try to modify your on condition like below.

```
 ON CAST (tCard.CardNumber as INT) = tMI.MI
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your both tables columns are different datatype so you use following
**cast** function in sql like

```
SELECT 
    cast(tMI.MI as varchar)  as MI
FROM
    tMI
LEFT JOIN 
    tCard ON tCard.CardNumber = tMI.MI
INNER JOIN
    TMIN on TMIN.T_ID = tMI.MI
WHERE
    tCard.CardNumber IS NULL
    AND tMI.MI IS NOT NULL
```